# PC Inventory Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$output.'AvailableDriveSpace (GB)' = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $server -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk |
Select-Object -Property DeviceID,@{Name='FreeSpace';Expression={ [Math]::Round(($_.Freespace / 1GB),1) }}
```

When running the script I built, I get all the correct information but it's displayed like this below

```
Processor                : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz
OperatingSystem          : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
AvailableDriveSpace (GB) : {@{DeviceID=C:; FreeSpace=4.9}, @{DeviceID=D:; FreeSpace=0}, @{DeviceID=H:; FreeSpace=194.7}, @{DeviceID=S:; FreeSpace=215.6}}
RAM (GB)                 : 8
UserProfileSize (GB)     : 17
```

Any ideas how I can get it more user friendly :)

Comment: you could iterate thru the drive list and make a property for each drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on what you think is a *more user friendly* output.

Perhaps something like this is what you're after?

```
$output = [PsCustomObject]@{
    'Processor'       = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor -ComputerName $Computer).Name -replace '\s+', ' '
    'OperatingSystem' = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Computer).Caption.Trim()

    'AvailableDriveSpace (GB)' = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer | ForEach-Object {
        'DeviceID = {0}  FreeSpace = {1}' -f $_.DeviceId, [Math]::Round(($_.Freespace / 1GB),1)
    } ) -join ([Environment]::NewLine)

    # get the user name who last logged on. The Where-Object clause filters out 
    # NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE etc.
    'LastLogOn' = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -ComputerName $Computer | 
                   Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike 'NT AUTHORITY*' } | 
                   ForEach-Object {
        'UserName = {0}  LastLogon = {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.LastLogon
    } ) -join ([Environment]::NewLine)

}
$output | fl *
```

Result:

> ```
> Processor                : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz
> OperatingSystem          : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
> AvailableDriveSpace (GB) : DeviceID = C:  FreeSpace = 86
>                            DeviceID = D:  FreeSpace = 390.3
>                            DeviceID = E:  FreeSpace = 313
>                            DeviceID = F:  FreeSpace = 0
>                            DeviceID = G:  FreeSpace = 0
> LastLogOn                : UserName = Domain\User  LastLogon = 12/16/2019 08:37:48
> ```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Just what I needed, got another enquiry with a similar issue - 
```
$output.'LastLogOn' = Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computer -ClassName Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Select-Object -Property Name,LastLogon 
```
Comes out like this - 
```
{NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (, NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE (, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE (, ANDREW-PC\(05/21/2018 08:37:48...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *manually* construct a friendly string representation of the array stored in `.AvailableDriveSpace (GB)`, which can you do as part of an explicit `Format-List` (or `Format-Table`) call:

```
./yourScript.ps1 |
  Format-List Processor,
              OperatingSystem, 
              @{ 
                n='AvailableDriveSpace (GB)'
                e={ 
                  $_.'AvailableDriveSpace (GB)'.ForEach({ 
                    '{0}={1}' -f $_.DeviceId, $_.FreeSpace
                  }) -join ' ' 
                } 
             },
             'RAM (GB)', 
             'UserProfileSize (GB)'
```

The above yields something like:

```
...
AvailableDriveSpace (GB) : C:=4.9 D:=0 H:=194.7 S:=215.6
...
```

Note that if you want your script *itself* to output this representation, you have the following options:

- Construct your object with the friendly string to begin with, instead of the structured, array-valued `AvailableDriveSpace (GB)` property, as shown in [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59359618/45375). If you don't need to programmatically process this property further, this may be acceptable.
- Otherwise, you'll have to give your output objects a self-chosen ETS type name and create *format data* for that virtual type *beforehand*, which allows you to control the default for-display formatting; note however, that that is a nontrivial effort - see [about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the object returned by the `Get-CimInstance` cmdlet to a string by using `Foreach-Object`:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $server -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk |
Select-Object -Property DeviceID,@{Name='FreeSpace';Expression={ [Math]::Round(($_.Freespace / 1GB),1) }} | 
Foreach-Object{$AvailSpace += $_.DeviceId + " (" + $_.FreeSpace + " available) "}
```

You can then set the `$output.'AvailableDriveSpace (GB)'` attribute to the `$AvailSpace` string created in the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet.